# Testing simple form validation on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I m trying to test react redux form validation, and I can't find what I m doing wrong in this test.

In my context, I have to display a simple message when the field value is less than 5 characters.

My validator works when I start my application in my browser and this is good.

My problem is concerning the test I should have written before make it work. It doesn't pass green :

```
it('should display a "Not long enough" in a class .field-error', () => {
      const input = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(searchBar, 'input');
      TestUtils.Simulate.focus(input);
      input.value = 'Test';
      TestUtils.Simulate.change(input);
      TestUtils.Simulate.blur(input);
      const fieldError = TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithClass(searchBar, 'field-error');
      expect(fieldError.textContent).toEqual('Not long enough');
    });
```

It fails telling me that it can't find the element field-error (which is well displayed when started in DOM).

How can I make that test pass ? I m pretty sure this is a test implementation problem...

I m using React, Redux, Redux Form and Redux-mock-store.

Thanks for your help.

EDIT : The rendering method concerned :

```
render() {
    const {fields: {inputField}} = this.props;
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Rechercher" {...inputField}/>
        {inputField.touched && inputField.error && <div className="field-error">{inputField.error}</div>}
        <button type="submit">Rechercher</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```